# Why are deformable cancer cells associated with being more malignant or dangerous?

Tags: cancer

So I was watching a lecture that talked about circulating tumor cells/cancer stem cells, and the professor mentioned that deformable cancer cells tend to be more dangerous to us. Why is this so? Does it have to do with the cells' physical ability to metastasize or intravasize better? Is it possible deformable cells are more resistant to drug therapy? (The latter suggestion sounds kind of crazy to me but if anyone has insights, a potential answer, or a research paper on it, I'd really appreciate it!!)

Comment: What was the exact term the professor used? "Squishy cancer cells" is unlikely to yield good results on searching. Try *deformability* and *metastasis*.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it could be something similar to what happens to RBCs where continuous peroxidation takes away their deformability so they break more easily and are taken up by macrophages when they get old. Deformable cancer cells may be similarly more stress resistant.

Comment: essentailly those cells are "stickier" because they are deformable and can adhere to a new site to begin growing easier. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6386247/ and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6386247/